# Batch (.bat) Backup Script > Empty folders not copied

Tags: batch-file, backup, batch-processing

This is the .bat script I use for my data backups:

```
ECHO OFF
set source="[source path]"
set destination="[destination path]"

for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set yyyymmdd1=%%j"."%%i"."%%k

if exist %destination% goto GO
:GO
mkdir %destination%%yyyymmdd1%
xcopy %source%* %destination%%yyyymmdd1% /s/d/y/c/v/r
echo. 
echo Finished copying %source% to %destination%
echo.
echo Created %destination%%yyyymmdd1%

pause
```

The main issue: It doesn't copy empty folders, so it requires an actual file inside in order to consider the folder itself.

The nice-to-have extension: The script currently compares source and destination folders by day and copies just the updated files. How would I achieve a destination folder structure comparison by day/date, followed by hour(= Folder("9/22/2017")/Folder("7am")/[full source folders/files]. This would enable me to fall back to files I created an hour ago if I had the script scheduled that frequently.

I adjusted the script above slightly according to my needs, but I am not the original creator. I am trying to get better at .bat scripting and help would be, as always, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aside from Magoo's helpful answer, the `if exist` and the label are useless as program flow will reach the next statement nevertheless. Also `mkdir` will create intermediate folders with enabledextensions (default). Your quoting scheme is a bit weird - why do you quote the dots in the date separately? Best quote only the complete path.

Answer (score 0):

The empty-directories problem: Read the documentation on `xcopy` (from the prompt: `xcopy /?`) and pay attention to the `/e` switch.

The time problem: Different people use different formats. There are many, many articles on SO about how to extract time into its elements in batch. Use the `search` facility in the top line to find them. You've already got a skeleton to append the `date` - it's essentially the same again.

The articles on time and date will also guide you on how to make adjustments for differing date/time formats in use, and likely make suggestions about the format that the date/time should take for the application for ease of sorting and recognition (ISO-style yyyymmddhhmmss)

Comment: Very helpful input! Just to be clear on the 2nd part: I don't want the .bat to create a folder it assigns a date and time to, I want it to create a date folder and within the date folder a time folder. It seems less of an issue of date/time format, than of reassigning the destination folder within a loop.

Comment: The `md` command will create any intermediate path segments required, so `md "some_path\yyyymmdd\hhmmss"` will create a date level and a time level below it (backslashes for directories - forward slashes are for switches in winbatch). The precise implementation is simply a question of placing the backslashes appropriately - but visually *reading* the date/time follows the yyyymmddhhmmss format.